# Deep learning for chatbot training

Tags: deep-learning, chatbot

We are trying to create an intelligent chatbot for customer service.  We have a corpus of customer service questions and answers, with a flagged intention of each conversation.  We are exploring to use Deep Learning to train our models but we encounter a couple of issues:

1. How to do feature engineering to train models on text data.  Specifically, how do you turn language into vectors ?
2. How to use non-word features that you use as input for the intent recognition deep learning classifier? How do you accommodate e.g. client product names?
3. How to choose a neural network architecture for Deep Learning with text input?
4. How can we deal with situations where we do not have enough data?  Use Bayesian techniques?

Comment: You may ask your question here to get more answers : http://stats.stackexchange.com/.
You will need to do Natural Language Processing (NLP), there are plenty of examples on the web. Try googling 'NLP feature extraction'.
Good luck !

Comment: The question/questions you are asking is whole course in itself. You need to learn NLP. If creating model from scratch is not mandatory then I will suggest you to use Google's API for chatbot development known as Dialogflow. Dialogflow is platform where you can easily develop the chatbot and with few clicks you can integrate it anywhere(website, facebook, slack even on google assistant etc.). Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

before you make jump to implementation, i would suggest please do learn some basics.

anyway, here are answers to your questions:

feature engineering : as name suggests , in your data there are something that may reduce accuracy of your model. like words mixed with small and capital character, digits ,special character , lines ends with some special character.. etc.  which after feature engineering gives more accuracy!! but again it's required all depends on what type of data you have !!

language into vectors : any type of language , at the end it is text (here in your case). we can give vector representation to word or character. this vector representation can be get by one hot vector or using pre-built methods like word2vec or glove.

one hot vector :- let's say you have 100 words from your training dataset . then create k-dimensional vector for each word. where k is total number of words. sord word by their character position. and based on thire sorted order create vector with keeping their index position 1 and rest as 0.

```
ex: [1 0 0 0 0 ....] - word1
    [0 1 0 0 0 ....] - word2
    [0 0 0 0 0 ...1] - word100
```

non-word features : follow same rule as word-features
client product name :- create one hot vector as they are not usually used in text. and they don't have meaning in real life.

how to choose NN :- it depends on what you want to achieve. NN can be used in many ways for many purpose.

not enough data :- it again depends on your data. !! if your data has more common pattern and in future data also these patterns going to come !! then it's still okay to use NN. else i don't recommend to use NN.